# SQLAlchemy recursive query result set ordering

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get hierarchical data using a recursive query with Python (3.9.6) and Flask-SqlAlchemy (2.5). This uses self-referential data where the parent_id of a record points to another record within the same table. Here's a simplified version of my model:

```py
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "post"
    post_id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("post.post_id"), default=None)
    content = db.Column(db.String)
    children = db.relationship("Post", backref=db.backref("parent", remote_side=[post_id], lazy="joined"))
```

And here's the SQLAlchemy query to get a post and all of its children (this uses a context manager to make sure the db session is either committed or rollback when the scope ends):

```py
    # post_id = unique id of a post in the database
    with db_session_manager() as db_session:
        # build the list of filters here to use in the CTE
        filters = [
            Post.post_id == post_id,
            Post.parent_id == None
        ]
        # construct a self-referential, hierarchal query for the
        # post and it's comments
        posts_hierarchy = (
            db_session.query(Post, literal(0).label('level'))
                .filter(*filters)
                .cte(name='post_hierarchy', recursive=True)
        )
        parent = aliased(posts_hierarchy, name="p")
        children = aliased(Post, name="c")
        posts_hierarchy = (
            posts_hierarchy.union_all(
                db_session.query(Post, (parent.c.level + 1).label("level"))
                .filter(children.parent_id == parent.c.post_id)
                .filter(Post.post_id == children.post_id)
            )
        )         
        posts = (
            db_session.query(Post, posts_hierarchy.c.level)
            .select_entity_from(posts_hierarchy)
            .all()
        )
```

This works as I get back the root post and all of its children, however, the result set contains this:

```
root post
     1st root child
     2nd root child
     3rd root child
          1st child child (1)
          2nd child child (2)
          3rd child child (3)
          2nd child child (4)
```

What I'd like to get back is this:

```
root post
     1st root child 
          1st child child (1)
          2nd child child (2)
          3rd child child (3)
     2nd root child
          2nd child child (4)
     3rd root child

etc
```

I'm not good enough with SQL to know to get the results I want. What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: Hi Doug. Please refrain from signing your posts if you can - historically the user card has been thought of as sufficient for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to get what I want from the recursive CTE query. I modified the database table like this:

```py
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "post"
    post_id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("post.post_id"), default=None)
    sort_key = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, default=SortKey())
    content = db.Column(db.String)
    children = db.relationship("Post", backref=db.backref("parent", remote_side=[post_id], lazy="joined"))
```

I added the sort_key column which is set to an autoincrementing function that returns a string version of the value. I updated my recursive CTE SqlAlchemy query to this:

```py
        # build the list of filters here to use in the CTE
        filters = [
            Post.post_uid == post_uid,
            Post.parent_uid == None
        ]
        if current_user.is_anonymous or current_user.can_view_posts():
            filters.append(Post.active == True)

        # build the recursive CTE query
        hierarchy = (
            db_session
                .query(Post, Post.sort_key.label("sorting_key"))
                .filter(*filters)
                .cte(name='hierarchy', recursive=True)
        )
        children = aliased(Post, name="c")
        hierarchy = hierarchy.union_all(
            db_session
                .query(
                    children,
                    (hierarchy.c.sorting_key + " " + children.sort_key).label("sorting_key")
                )
                .filter(children.parent_uid == hierarchy.c.post_uid)
        )
        # query the hierarchy for the post and it's comments
        posts = (
            db_session
                .query(Post, hierarchy.c.sorting_key)
                .select_entity_from(hierarchy)
                .order_by(hierarchy.c.sorting_key)
                .all()
        )
```

The synthetic `sorting_key` value is a concatenated set of the `sort_key` from the table and is used to correctly sort the results into the hierarchical format I'm looking for. This is based on two resources [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html#recursive-cte-with-indented-output) and [here](https://gist.github.com/cairabbit/d64fccf7cf2abe180e69c843706f46c7?utm_source=pocket_mylist).

Hope others find this helpful